# Load an image in Jira Plugin Page from the image path in server

Tags: jira, jfreechart, velocity, jira-plugin

I am working in a plugin which generates a chart from the data from the plugin. The chart is generated using org.jfree.chart packages. The png file generated in stored in the temp directory in my tomcat.

Now the requirement is that I want to load this image in one of my plugin page. Previously in Jira(prior to 6.3) this was done by using this syntax in .vm file

```
<img 
        width="10"
        height="10"
        src="${req.contextPath}/charts?filename=${chartName}"/>
```

But now this does not seem to be working. My requirement is to get this file from the tmp directory and load it in the page through the vm file.

I am able to get the exact path to the png file but not able to load it as the file seems to be not found all the time.

Please guide me with some inputs.

Comment: Why not use `ChartUtilities` to write to a `java.io.OutputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @trashgod

I was able to write the image byte array to the HttpServletResponse and then load it on the client side.

By this way I dont need to create the file and store it in any temp folder. rather create it on the go and load it directly from the response.